# dynamic nested form always creates an extra blank entry - using formtastic_coocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, formtastic

I'm using formtastic & formtastic_cocoon to created a nested form.

All seems to be working well dynamically adding a nested form to an existing form, with one exception.

I have users and users have entries.

When I create a user, and add an entry, I end up with

```
-User
   - Entry (empty)
   - Entry Test 1
```

I should only have

```
-User
   - Entry Test 1
```

I'm not sure why the blank entry is always showing up.

My models are

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, :presence => true
   has_attached_file :photo

   has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true

end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :entry

   belongs_to :user


end
```

my create controller is (I think this is the right controller)

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created user."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

 def create
    @task = Task.new(params[:task])
    if @task.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created task."
      redirect_to @task
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

The empty entries are showing up in the database, so I don't think it is a problem with the html.erb files, but I can post those here if that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this may be an issue with the way formtastic_cocoon handles forms.

When looking at the html source, the nested form is in the page, but hidden.

I changed the model to

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :reject_if=> proc {|attributes| attributes[:entry].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true
```

Comment: Note that with the current version of `cocoon` (the replacement of `formtastic-cocoon`) this is no longer necessary.

Comment: But it is necessary for `formtastic` only.